# CSV Export with NULL and comma Data

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server version 2017. SSMS version 18.
I used 'Data export/Import' wizard of SSMS.

This table has two rows.
C1 / C2 / C3 are column name and NULL is null value.

```
C1 | C2            | C3
1  | NULL          | Test
2  | Apple, Banana | Test3
```

When I export CSV without quotation. 
CSV format can not use because Data include comma; 'Apple, Banana'

```
1,,Test
2,Apple, Banana,Test3
```

When I export CSV with quotation. 
Also CSV format can not use because I can't distinguish "" is NULL or empty Stirng.

```
"1","","Test"
"2","Apple, Banana","Test3"
```

So, I hope When the data is null value.
CSV format like this.

```
"1",NULL,"Test"
"2","Apple, Banana","Test3"
```

How should I use do that? Is there only way using IFNULL function on Query?

Comment: I can't replicate the result you do. With a row with the value `NULL` I get `"1","","test"` not `"NULL"`. Also, in *all* the time i have been using SSIS, I've never had it export a `NULL` value as anything other than a blank string. From a CSV's perspective as well, `NULL` and `"NULL"` are the *same* value; they don't have a "null" data type, it's **all** a string.

Comment: There are no NULLs in a text file, everything is a string. `NULL` is a string with the letters N, U, L and L. There are [people named Null](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20160325-the-names-that-break-computer-systems) and there's [an interesting story behind this Irish-derived name](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-some-peoples-last-names-null). And [quite a few systems that crash](https://www.wired.com/2015/11/null/) when they encounter it

Comment: There is an actual NUL character (0x00) that's non-visible but no application expects it. Visibly it's no different than an empty string (it's unprintable after all). You could use that but you'd have to modify other applications to recognize it. Or you can use the convention that `,"",` is an empty string while `,,` is a missing value. Once again you'd have to configure readers to handle this convention

Comment: Thank you comment.. Well... I decided  `SELECT IFNULL(c1, 'NULL', '"c1,"'), IFNULL(c2, 'NULL', '"c2,"') ..` .